# How to open a new LWC in a new tab when a button is clicked on parent LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a requirement to open a new Tab in which LWC is rendered and I new to pass attributes to display in that component.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "I new to pass attributes"? In general I have difficulties to understand what the circumstances are. (And please don't just present requirements and hope that someone else is doing your job - present what you already have!)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. We expect a certain level of effort before questions are asked and for this effort to be demonstrated using code snippets or citing research undertaken. See [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for details. Please [edit] your question to provide these details. If you do not, you will likely find the question is closed without answer.

Comment: NB: LWCs are not URL addressable. However, you could write a wrapper Aura component that is. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [basic navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_basic) in LWC from the parent component. As the LWC is not URL Addressable directly as of now, we have two solutions (below):

1. [Wrap the target LWC](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/06/07/navigate-to-lightning-web-component-from-another-lightning-web-component/) in an URL Addressable Aura component
2. Use [standard__webPage navigation type](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/06/08/directly-navigate-to-lightning-web-component-without-using-aura-component/) for the target LWC

I haven't tried these myself and found them in a quick google search. Please give both of these a try and let me know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: It worked thank you